# css make a dropdow appear under ajoining text: please see screenshot

Tags: css

the client want something like this.  I can manage the styling (corners and all) but i can't get the "dropdown" to drop under the text in the cell to the left.  My html follows.  Thanks in advance

[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div.outside').hide();

            $('div.selector').click(function () {
                var hidden = $(this).parents('td').find('div.outside :hidden').length > 0;
                $('div.outside').hide();
                if (hidden) {
                    $(this).parents('td').find('div.outside').show().animate('slow');
                } else {
                    $(this).parents('td').find('div.outside').hide().animate('slow');
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul.action
        {
            list-style-type: none;
            list-style-position: outside;
            padding: 0px;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        ul li
        {
            margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
        }
        div.content
        {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 1px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        div.outside
        {
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        div.top
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
        div.selector
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
            float: right;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            top: 2px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .popup-dropdown
        {
            background-color: #FFFFE1;
        }
        thead td
        {
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Rank
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 20px;">
                    Style
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Jimmi Hendrix
            </td>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                Blues-Rock
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20px;">
                <div class='top'>
                    <div class='selector popup-dropdown'>
                        X</div>
                </div>
                <div style='clear: both;'>
                </div>
                <div class='outside'>
                    <div class='content popup-dropdown'>
                        <ul class='action'>
                            <li>Make God Status</li>
                            <li>Elevate</li>
                            <li>Respect</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Carlos Santana
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                Blues-Rock
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20px;">
                <div class='top'>
                    <div class='selector popup-dropdown'>
                        X</div>
                </div>
                <div style='clear: both;'>
                </div>
                <div class='outside'>
                    <div class='content popup-dropdown'>
                        <ul class='action'>
                            <li>Make God Status</li>
                            <li>Elevate</li>
                            <li>Respect</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vulputate pulvinar
    nisi vel tincidunt. Mauris eget pulvinar enim. Suspendisse vitae turpis id orci
    porttitor auctor nec ut nisi. Nunc euismod. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so.... what goes wrong?  I can see that you want to emulate some kind of dropdown and you can't seem to get it under the text of the cell to the left, but when I put the code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5bn4/) it seems to work correctly.

Comment: in the spec  screenshot you'll see that the "drop down arrow" is much closer to the cell on the left

Comment: @Joseph jsfiddle rocks!  the containing <td> is 200px to accomodate div.outside.  I only want the cell to be 20px wide and have div.outside "float" the extra 180px to the left under the text "Blues Rock". Its close, but...

Comment: what I'm looking for is how to position the "drop down" element NNpx to the right of the 3rd cell

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.  Correct me if I misunderstood, but I think you wanted to just basically get rid of that gap next to the 'X' and have the right edge of the popup aligned with the right edge of the 'X' box.  You can accomplish this with absolute positioning.  I've made changes to the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F5bn4/2

I changed the inline style on the `td`s and I changed 200px to 20px on `div.top`